# Constant server pings

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, logging, django, heroku

I've got a Python/Django app hosted on Heroku, monitored on New Relic, with logging tracked on Logentries.  I've noticed a large amount of logs that are of the form:

> at=info
>   method=HEAD
>   path="/"
>   host=mysite.com
>   fwd="xxx.xx.xxx.xx/ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

If I look at a span of 10 minutes, I have 50 pings. 5 per minute that occur at regular intervals of exactly 60 seconds.

There are 5 individual fwd addresses that ping once every minute.

One of them is new relic because the fwd address ends with "nr-ops.net" and I have NR set up for availability monitoring.

The other 4 IPs direct to either AWS machines or Digital Ocean machines.

So I'm comfortable with the New Relic checks, but who are the other guys? I have two web dynos and a celery server set up on my app, so are those three servers pinging each other? Maybe a third is my CloudAMQP server?

Should I be concerned at all about this? I don't believe the HEAD requests are counted towards my throughput monitoring, but could this affect request queueing and performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A ping every 10 seconds really isn't going to cause any performance issues. The AWS pings are probably sent directly from Amazon (Heroku is on the Amazon AWS marketplace, so it's probably hosted by them) to keep statistics on uptime/latency/etc. If someone was probing your box it would be followed up with more invasive scans.